# 2 sequences converging to the same number

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to prove that $\{x_n\}-\{y_n\} \to 0,  n \to \infty$

A sequence is said to converge if and only if for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|x_n-a|\lt\epsilon$

If both sequences converge to the same number $a_1 = a_2$ where $x_n$ converges to $a_1$ and $y_n$ converges to $a_2$

Would it follow that?:

$|x_n-a_1| \lt \epsilon - |y_n-a_2|\lt \epsilon$

$x_n-a_1 - y_n + a_2 \lt 0$

$x_n-y_n \lt 0$

Can someone provide geometric idea of what is going on?

Comment: Use $\left| x_n-y_n \right|$ and the triangle inequality to get a standard $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ proof.

Comment: Your reasoning is confused. Yes, you have $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. And $|y_n-a|<\epsilon$ for $n>N'$, so both inequalities hold for $n>max(N,N')$. But it doesn't follow that $x_n-a-y+a<0$. You can't subtract inequalities. If you change the sign the inequality reverses, so $-\epsilon<-|y_n-a|$. Then adding gives $|x_n-a|-\epsilon<-|y_n-a|+\epsilon$, which is no different from just adding!

Comment: is this equivalent to using the triangle inequality as below? I assume the absolute values remain and its not like you algebraicically solve for $x_n, yn$

Comment: Also when using the triangle inequality is it $|x_n - L -(y_n -L)| = |x_n -y_n+L|\leq |x_n-L|+|y_n-L|$? I am confused as how we go from $|x_n - y_n|$ to the triangle?

Comment: Can someone show how this limit approaches 0 from the inequality?

Comment: You have the right idea Gibson. The middle expression isn't quite correct though:
$ \left| x_n-y_n \right| = \left| x_n - L + L - y_n \right| \leq \left| x_n-L \right| + \left| L-y_n \right| = \left| x_n - L \right| + \left| y_n-L \right|$. For n large enough both terms on the right are arbitrarily small, say, smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: What about the limit?

Comment: How does this approach zero?

Comment: Hi K.Gibson. Recall that the limit here is given in the form of an $\epsilon$ argument; by showing the value is less than an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ you are showing (in a formal and rigorous way) that the limit is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the common limit $L$, then for a given $\epsilon >0$, you have

$$|x_n-L| \lt \epsilon/2 ,(n>N_1)$$

and  $$ |y_n-L|\lt \epsilon/2, ( n>N_2)$$

Thus $$ |x_n -y_n|\le |x_n-L|+|y_n-L|<\epsilon$$

For $n> \max \{N_1, N_2\}$

That is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (x_n-y_n) =0 $$

Comment: Can someone show how this limit approaches 0 from the inequality?

Comment: Let $\epsilon $ goes to zero.

Comment: @K.Gibson What's the _definition_  of "$\lim(x_n-y_n)=0"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich For every positive $\epsilon$ there exists an $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|x_n-y_n|<\epsilon$

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I asked K. Gibson - the idea bring that he'd figure out the answer to his question by considering what I asked...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  I should not have answered your question. I need to be more patient.